# use optional parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Compare
    @lst varchar(100),
    @frst varchar(100) = NULL,
    @passportNo varchar(50) = NULL
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.User
WHERE LastName like '%' + @lst + '%'
    AND (
         FirstName like @frst + ' %'
         OR FirstName like '% ' + @frst + ' %'
         OR FirstName like '% ' + @frst
         OR FirstName = @frst
        )
    OR Passport = @passportNo;
```

Sometimes `@frs` or `@passportNo` or both the details may not be available

so I want to change the above query such that when optional parameter is not passed(ie., when its value is null) that parameter shouldn't be considered for filtering on that particular column

viz., if `@frst` is NULL then result shouldn't be filtered based in FirstName, it should work as if there was no `FirstName like '%' + @frst + '%'` condition in WHERE clause..

How can I write the query without writing the same logic repeatedly for different cases?

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has mentioned this in the 5.5 years since this question was asked, but it's a really bad idea to name your stored procs *sp_*. Microsoft recommends against it

Comment: [lost edit]Microsoft recommends against it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) in case of name clashes, but I also think it adversely affects performance (don't know if this is still the case with current versions), as SQL server looks for sp_procs in a different places before using the expected _Stored Procedures_ area in your db.

Comment: Yes the documentation in @Justin 's link says: *Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
WHERE (@frst IS NULL OR 
    (
         LastName like '%' + @lst + '%'
         AND (
             FirstName like @frst + ' %'
             OR FirstName like '% ' + @frst + ' %'
             OR FirstName like '% ' + @frst
             OR FirstName = @frst
        )
    )
 )
 AND (@passportNo IS NULL OR
        Passport = @passportNo);
```

**Edit**: Actually this should be more efficient:

```
WHERE ( @frst IS NULL OR FirstName like '%' + @frst + '%' )
AND   ( @lst  IS NULL OR LastName  like '%' + @lst  + '%' )
AND   ( @passportNo IS NULL OR Passport = @passportNo )
```

Comment: And only the `FirstName like '% ' + @frst + ' %'` is needed - the rest 3 conditions are redundant.