# SQL add filter only if a variable is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have query as follows:

```
    SELECT  route_id [ROUTE_ID]
    FROM route_master(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  route_ou = 2
    AND   route_query = @l_s_query
    AND   lang_id  = 1
```

Here, the " AND route_query = @l_s_query" condition in WHERE clause should be added only when @l_s_query is non empty. I donot want to write IF ELSE condition for @l_s_query. Is there any way to handle in WHERE clause itself directly.Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `... AND (route_query = @l_s_query OR @l_s_query IS NULL) ...`?

Comment: add this `AND  (@l_s_query IS NULL OR route_query = @l_s_query)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use optional parameter in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814893/use-optional-parameter-in-where-clause)

Comment: The question in the title "is not null" disagrees with the question in the header "is non empty" (since we call zero-length strings "empty"). This is why you've got two different answers, from sagi and Tamas.

Comment: I've previously used a CASE statement in queries like this, with the value being the same in a false case eg.  `... AND route_query = (CASE WHEN @l_s_query is not null THEN @l_s_query ELSE route_query END)`

Answer (score 25):

You can translate your requirement into :

```
SELECT  route_id [ROUTE_ID]
FROM route_master(NOLOCK)
WHERE  route_ou = 2
AND   (@l_s_query is null OR route_query = @l_s_query)
AND   lang_id  = 1
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is optional but can give better execution plans at the expense of extra compilation time as discussed in the canonical article on the topic [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Or with `COALESCE()` to avoid the `OR` :

```
WHERE  route_ou = 2
AND   COALESCE(@l_s_query,route_query) = route_query 
AND   lang_id  = 1
```

**Note:** As @jarlh said, if `route_query` is nullable, this may cause some issues becuase of null comparison, so you may want to use the first query.

Another option of this is two separate queries using `UNION ALL` , one for each condition -

```
SELECT .. FROM .. 
WHERE @l_s_query IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT .. FROM .. 
WHERE @l_s_query = route_query
```

On terms of performance,only the last one will use the index, I believe the first one will be the fastest, but it may change depanding on the indexes, sizes of the tables ETC..

Comment: Second query is a bit different when it comes to NULL values in route_query.

Comment: @jarlh Yea.. I've added a comment about this:)

Comment: what about performance implications? does this kind of expression not prevent index use, or are recent versions of mssql smart enough to account for that? I remember it was sometimes necessary to write two copies of such `SELECT`s, one with the parameter in the WHERE clause and one without, wrapped in an IF ... ELSE ... END

Comment: COALESCE(@l_s_query,route_query) = route_query  ,  just found out first hand, this can cause problem if the value is null and the search parameter is null, null = null does not evaluate to true it seems.

Answer (score 4):

> the " AND route_query = @l_s_query" condition in WHERE clause should be added only when @l_s_query is non empty.

```
    WHERE  route_ou = 2
    AND   (  (@l_s_query IS NOT NULL AND route_query = @l_s_query ) OR
              @l_s_query IS NULL ) 
    AND   lang_id  = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way to handle: using `LEN(ISNULL)... OR`:

```
AND (LEN(ISNULL(@l_s_query,'')) = 0 OR route_query = @l_s_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate if-else with an OR:

```
AND ((0 = len(@l_s_query) OR @l_s_query IS NULL OR route_query = @l_s_query)
```

Explanation:

- `AND (...)` - the parentheses is required to apply the non-empty check only for this predicate
- `0 < len(@l_s_query)` - is a way to determine non-emptiness for `varchar`-s.

Comment: Your query will return zero results if`@l_s_query` is `NULL` or empty.

Comment: Indeed, `OR` is the right fallback-operator. Fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: Your syntax is off. You are missing an operator, I think. `IS EMPTY` doesn't seem to exist, though. And if `@l_s_query` is non-empty, it isn't checked against `route_query`.

Comment: Rght, fixed them too. If `@l_s_query` is checked against `route_query` if and only if it isn't empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  route_id [ROUTE_ID]
FROM route_master(NOLOCK)
WHERE  route_ou = 2
AND   (route_query = @l_s_query AND @l_s_query IS NOT NULL)
AND   lang_id  = 1
```