# Add filter only if the variable is given with values in Metabase

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, metabase

In Metabase, one can add variables with `{{variable}}` in queries, such as:

```
select *
from dashboard_demographic_view
where clinic_id = {{clinic}}
```

, where `dashboard_demographic_view` is a view created in advance. In the query above, rows where `clinic_id` matches what is given in `{{clinic}}` will be returned.

Still, I am curious what if I need that filter only when I give `{{clinic}}` a value, or otherwise the query should return all the rows. I've referred to [SQL add filter only if a variable is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828272/sql-add-filter-only-if-a-variable-is-not-null) but it is not helping in my case.

```
select *
from dashboard_demographic_view
where ({{clinic}} is null or clinic_id = {{clinic}})
```

The query above gives *Unable to substitute 'clinic': param not specified. Found: ("clinic")* when I don't specify `clinic`.

Theoretically this can be solved by making the variable `{{clinic}}` a field filter. However, for some reasons that cannot be done for a view ([#8800 in metabase](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/8800)).

I am seeking workarounds other than making a real table to fulfill my purposes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would optional clauses help you here? See the end of [Metabase Documentation: Sql Parameters](https://metabase.com/docs/v0.20.0/users-guide/12-sql-parameters.html).

Your code would essentially become something like

```
select *
from dashboard_demographic_view
[[where clinic_id = {{clinic}})]]
```

(This question has probably been asked earlier too – maybe worth checking if there are duplicates  inside Stack Overflow.)