# Is there a way to select all records where value = all or none, depending on the selected filter SQL?

Tags: sql

So, I have a website where a user could display all tutors within the database. The user has a choice to select search filters, such as displaying tutors from Durbanville only, or displaying females only... So, the question is, Instead of writing code for each filter possibility, I would like to have one function which will display all records based on the input of 5 filter options.

For example:

- Gender : Male or Female or all
- Suburb : Bellville, Durbanville, Brackenfell or all
- Age range : 5-10; 11-16; 17 +; or all
  ...

I would like to have something like this,
select * from tutors where gender = (male or female or all) and suburb = (Bellville, Durbanville, Brackenfell or all) and Age range = (5-10; 11-16; 17 +; or all).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL add filter only if a variable is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828272/sql-add-filter-only-if-a-variable-is-not-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use is null along with the conditions like this -
lets say input parameters are inpgen, inpsub, and inpage.

```
SELECT ...
FROM table 
WHERE
(inpgen is null OR inpgen in ('Male','Female'))
AND (inpsub is null OR inpsub in ('Bellville', 'Durbanville', 'Brackenfell'))
AND ( inpage  is null OR inpage between 5 and 17)
```

So, when user selects only age other two conditions will be null and they will return all values. In one of our tool, it needed to consider inpgen ='' instead of null.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried using your solution but seems like it does not recognize that sql statement. I will go try again and ensure that I did not do something wrong, but seems like it does not work. But thanks anyway

Comment: i fixed my sql. could you pls try it?

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks so much, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes ou wat sê jy. Not sure what datatype your AGE is. But if Age was CHAR:

```
SELECT
*
FROM table 
WHERE
Gender IN (('Male', 'Female') OR (Gender LIKE ('Male' AND 'Female')))
AND (Suburb is NULL OR Suburb IN ('Bellville', 'Durbanville', 'Brackenfell'))
AND (Age IN ('5-10', '11-16', '17+') OR AGE IS NULL)
```

IF Age was INT:

```
AND ((Age = 5 < Age) OR (AGE IS NULL))
```

Comment: Yes yes, baie dankie maar die vorige antwoord het my problem gesolve, maar tnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

For Future Reference, a generic Solution

```
Declare @inpgen varchar(100) = 'Female'; Declare @inpsub varchar(100) = 'Mohali'; Declare @inpage int = 23;

SELECT *
FROM Tutor t 
Where 
    (@inpgen is null OR t.Gender = @inpgen)      
    AND
    (@inpsub is null OR t.Suburb = @inpsub)
    AND
    (@inpage is null OR t.Age between @inpage and @inpage + 5)
```