# Conditional AND to include in WHERE condition using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

In LINQ we can ignore or not include a particular condition in query like this:

```
var resutls = from emp in dbContext.Employees
              where emp.IsActive == true
                    && (payload.Type.HasValue? emp.Type == payload.Type : true)
```

In this above code in LINQ, if `payload.Type.HasValue` is true, then this condition will be included in query. What is the alternative of this ternary operator and conditional include in a SQL Server stored procedure?

I want to include this `AND e.Type = IF @Type > 0 THEN @Type ELSE 1`: if the Type is provided or it's greater then 0.

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetEmployees]
    @Type INT
AS
    SELECT e.Id, e.Title, e.Email
    FROM Employees e
    WHERE e.IsActive = 1
      AND e.Type = IF @Type <> NULL THEN @Type
```

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and should *not* be used for User Stored Procedures. Doing so can cause your Procedure to suddenly stop working after an update/upgrade and comes with a performance hit.

Comment: Another note - learn how to work with NULL values. NULL is unknown. You cannot compare it in any way to another value in boolean logic and get a true/false result.

Comment: As @Larnu already said: Microsoft has [reserved the `sp_` prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL add filter only if a variable is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828272/sql-add-filter-only-if-a-variable-is-not-null)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use boolean logic:

```
WHERE e.IsActive = 1 AND
      (@Type IS NULL OR e.Type = @Type)
```

I would provide some caution though.

First, the above does not all the select only of values when `Type` is `NULL`.  Neither does your original code, but if that is desirable, some other method is needed to specify "all rows".

Second, the above may not make optimal use of indexes, based on the way that SQL Server caches plans for stored procedures.  There are mechanisms to get around that when necessary.

Third, I strongly discouraging returning a result set from a stored procedure when you can easily write a table-valued function to do the same thing.  Then you can use the results in a query.

Comment: I disagree with the third point; there are plenty of good reasons to return a data set from a Procedure, especially when implementing the rule of minimisation for permissions for an application; having the Application only being able to execute Procedures is a great way to minimise those permissions.

Comment: @Larnu The third point is about having a stored function instead of a stored procedure, not about using ad-hoc SQL instead of stored objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that payLoad is a local variable (= not in the database).

The method that you use now, forces Payload to be sent to the database, and every Employee the ternary expression is evaluated.

It would be way more efficient if your process would evaluate it once, and decide which Expression to send to the database:

```
var payload = ...
IQueryable<Employee> queryEmployees;
if (payload.Type.HasValue)
{
    var payLoadType = payLoad.Type.Value;
    queryEmployees = dbContext.Employees
        .Where(employee => employee.IsActive && employee.Type == payloadType);
}
else
{
    queryEmployees = dbContext.Employees.Where(employee => employee.IsActive);
}
```

If you will use this only once, I would leave it like this. However, if you will use this on several locations, consider to create a method for this. The nicest thing would be and extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx).

```
public static IQueryable<Employee> WhereActivePayLoadType(
    this IQueryable<Employee> employees,
    Payload payload)
{
    // TODO: invent a proper name
    // TODO: check input parameters for null

    // code from above:
    if (payload.Type.HasValue)
    {
        var payLoadType = payLoad.Type.Value;
        return employees.Where(employee => employee.IsActive
                                        && employee.Type == payloadType);
    }
    else
    {
        return Employees.Where(employee => employee.IsActive);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Payload payload = ...
var result = dbContext.Employees.WhereActivePayloadType(payload)
    .Select(employee => ...)
    .ToList();
```

By using payLoad as parameter, I hide the internals of Payload: if Payload changes internally, for instance payLoad.Type changes to a non-nullable type, users won't have to change their query. If you don't want this, or if you want to be able to `Where` on something else, consider to use the nullable parameter payloadType instead.

Or, if you are feeling adventurous, and you see that you use this construction with nullable types more often, consider to use a really generic method, that can be used with any table type and any nullable:

- Input: a queryable sequence of type TSource
- Input: a property selector that selects a property of TSource. This property has type TProperty
- Input a parameter `value` of type TProperty?, that has the nullable filter value
- Output: if value has no value: the input sequence; otherwise, the input sequence where the value of the selected property equals value.

.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereValue<TSource, TProperty>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty> propertySelector,
    TProperty? value)
{
    // TODO: check input parameters

    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        TProperty = nonNullValue = value.HasValue;
        return source.Where(item => propertySelector(item) == nonNullValue);
    }
    else
        return source;
}
```

In words: if value equals null, return the source sequence.

If value equals non-null, get this nonNullValue. We know that this nonNullValue is not null, so it is of type TProperty. For every item in the source sequence, select the property that the propertySelector defines. This property is also of type TProperty. Keep only those items from the source sequence where this property has a value equal to nonNullValue.

Usage:

```
Payload payload = ...
dbContext.Employees
    .Where(employee => employee.IsActive)
    .WhereValue(employee => employee.Type, payload => payload.Type);
```

But now you can also use it for other classes. For instance, if you have Customers, and a ComboBox with PostCodes. If nothing selected, then you want all Customers, if one selected, then you want Customes with that PostCode:

```
PostCode? selectedPostCode = this.ComboBox.IsSelected ? 
    (PostCode?) this.ComboBox.SelectedValue :
    (PostCode?) null;

var selectedCustomers = dbContext.Customers
    .WhereValue (customer => customer.PostCode, selectedPostCode);
```