# Dynamic where condition in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

This is my SQL Server stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC test_sp
@id int,
@ipVal varchar(20) = null,
@browserName varchar(20) = null
as
begin
select * from users where id=@id order by id desc;
end
```

I want to change my `where` condition in this dynamically.

When `@ipVal is not null`, I should pass all the three parameters in Where condition. When my `@ipVal is null`, then I should pass only `id=@id` in where condition.

How to do this in SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL add filter only if a variable is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828272/sql-add-filter-only-if-a-variable-is-not-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can chnage your where clause to this :

```
select * from users 
where id=@id
and (@ipVal is null or (browserName=@browserName and ipval=@ipVal))
```