# SQL Server 2008 - nvarchar concatenation cuts off ISNULL() replacement value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have a stored procedure in which I have a default `WHERE` clause nvarchar with the following:

```sql
DECLARE @DEFAULT_WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DEFAULT_WHERE = N'RTRIM(LTRIM(DD.CODIGO)) = '  +isnull(''''+@ID_CODIGODENUNCIA+'''',   N'LTRIM(RTRIM(dd.CODIGO))') +' AND 
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(TI.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_INGRESO+'''',          'LTRIM(RTRIM(ti.ID))')     +' AND 
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(TD.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_DELITO+'''',           'LTRIM(RTRIM(td.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(AD.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_LOCATIZACION+'''',     'LTRIM(RTRIM(ad.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(EF.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_FASE+'''',             'LTRIM(RTRIM(ef.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(EE.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_ESTADO+'''',           'LTRIM(RTRIM(ee.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(EA.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ESTADO_ACTIVIDAD+'''',    'LTRIM(RTRIM(ea.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(TR.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@ID_RECEPCION+'''',        'LTRIM(RTRIM(tr.ID))')     +' AND
                       RTRIM(LTRIM(SU.ID)) = '      +isnull(''''+@USUARIO_CREACION+'''',    'LTRIM(RTRIM(su.ID))')
```

Basically if a parameter is not set, the simply use the default value.

The problem is that when I select `@DEFAULT_WHERE` with no parameter set (so they are all null) I get this:

```sql
RTRIM(LTRIM(DD.CODIGO)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(TI.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ti.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(TD.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(td.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(AD.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ad.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(EF.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ef.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(EE.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ee.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(EA.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ea.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(TR.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(tr.ID))
AND RTRIM(LTRIM(SU.ID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(su.ID
```

So 'dd.CODIGO))' and '))' in the last AND clause get cut off.

When I remove the `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` and just write `dd.CODIGO`, it does not get cut off, but I need the trimming.

Any suggestions on how to rewrite this nvarchar?

Comment: What is the datatype of `@ID_CODIGODENUNCIA`? `ISNULL` returns the datatype of the first parameter so you can see truncation if the second value doesn't fit in that

Comment: If you are going into the trouble of building the `where` clause dynamically, then omit the pointless filters completely rather than turning them into dummy comparisons. The dummy comparisons are for when you [don't build the `where` clause dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828313/11683).

Comment: `ISNULL` returns the data the of the **first** parameter. If, therefore, the second parameter has a longer length than the first, it will be truncated. Perhaps `COALESCE` would be a better choice, which is a short hand `CASE` expression and uses data type precedence.

Comment: All those functions in you where clause are rendering this statement nonsargable and the performance is going to be less than great. Also, sql server 2008 has been fully unsupported for more than 5 years now. Time to get your upgrade path sorted out.

Comment: Agree with @GSerg, see [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).